# How to Change KeyList KeyCode to Crossplatformmobileinput?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, keycode

i want to change keycode input to crossplatforminput to be able to played on android device , but its really hard
below is a code code related to my problem

and I have tried tweaking based on my knowledge, and i have tried to googling it but still dont find the answer

```
 private List<KeyList> _keysList;

void Update() {
      if (!photonView.isMine || _player.Hp.Cur.Value <= 0 || _player.State.Rigor || !IsCorrectAnimationState() || _player.Debuff.State[DebuffType.Stun])
        return;
      for (int i=0; i<_keysList.Count; ++i) {
        if (_player.Level.Cur.Value < _requireLv[i])
          continue;
        if (_isDisabled[i] && (_player.Level.Cur.Value == _requireLv[i]))
          EnableSkill(i);

        for (int k=0; k<_keysList[i].keys.Count; ++k) {
          if (_canUseList[i] && CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButton(_keysList[i].keys[k])) {
            InstantiateSkill(i);
            StartCT(i);
            UpdateCT(i);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }


 public class KeyList {
    public List<KeyList> keys;
  }
```

the result is still failed , because I can't solve the problem yet

Comment: `the result is still failed , because I can't solve the problem yet` ... what are you even trying? what exactly is supposed to happen and where does it fail?

Comment: I have tried tweaking based on my knowledge, and i have tried to googling it but still dont find the answer